# Two-way binding nested objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following class in my Angular2 app:

```
export class MyClass {
  name: Object;
}
```

The name object has a dynamic property to load the current language. Currently, when I want to do two-way binding, I'm doing like this:

```
item: MyClass = {
  name: { en: string }
}
```

That way, in my HTML, I just use `[(ngModel)]="item.name.en"`. However, I have many other properties in that class as well.

Do I have to define all of them inside `item`? If I try to call only `MyClass` (`item: MyClass;`), I get `undefined error`.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

(1) Avoid using `Object` as a type, as [noted in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

> The any type is a powerful way to work with existing JavaScript,
>   allowing you to gradually opt-in and opt-out of type-checking during
>   compilation.
>   **You might expect Object to play a similar role, as it does in other languages. But variables of type Object only allow you to assign any
>   value to them - you can’t call arbitrary methods on them, even ones
>   that actually exist**

So it's better to go with `any`:

```
export class MyClass {
    name: any;
}
```

But then you lose the type safety feature the typescript is giving you (same if you use `Object`), why not:

```
export class MyClass {
    name: { [language: string]: string };
}
```

(2) Doing this:

```
item: MyClass = {
    name: { en: string }
}
```

Is problematic in that it does not create a new instance of `MyClass`, it only creates an object with the same properties (the reason that it compiles with no errors is because ["typescript is based on structural subtyping"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)).

If you want to create an instance then:

```
item = Object.assign(new MyClass(), {
    name: { en: string }
});
```

Or you can create a constructor which populates the data:

```
export class MyClass {
    name: { [language: string]: string };

    copnstructor(name: { [language: string]: string }) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

item = new MyClass({
    name: { en: string }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The **name** property in **MyClass** is type of **Object**, if you want to define custom property in **name**, then create a separate class like **NameClass**

```
class NameClass { 
  en: string;
  otherProp: any
}
```

Then use it in **MyClass**

```
class MyClass {
  name: NameClass
}
```

And the second thing, when you are creating an object like this `item: MyClass;` then it's just an empty variable. Nothing is being assigned there.

if the **typescript** code `item: MyClass;` is converted to **JS** you will just see the line as `var item;` which is **undefined**.

Hope it helps.